# Laravel updating multiple relationships with 1 save

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have seen things around the internet related to this, but either I cant quite seem to understand it or the answer is very old and related to an older version of laravel, so could someone explain to me how to do this?

So lets say I have a master model of `users`, and my users model has multiple relationships like so

```
public function contacts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Users\UserContacts', 'user_id', 'id');
}

public function discounts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Users\UserDiscounts','user_id', 'id');
}
```

Then inside an update function, i'm updating the user and relationships like this

```
//Get the user to update
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
$user->name = $request->name;
$user->age  = $request->age;
$user->discounts->amount = $request->discount_amount;
$user->discounts->start_date = $request->discount_start_date;
$user->contacts->name = $request->contact_name;
$user->contacts->email = $request->contact_email;
```

How do I save this so that it saves the user model and all the relationships?

```
$user->save(); //Only works for user model
$user->update(); //Only works for user model
$user->discounts->save(); //Only works for discount model
```

I have a very large list of relationships, and ideally I would like to be able to save them all with 1 command. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: You could use a non-model query to accomplish that, like `DB::table("UserDiscounts")->where("user_id", "=", $user->id)->update(["amount" => $request->input("discount_amount"), "start_date" => $request->input("discount_start_date")]);` (Note, not 100% on that syntax, but something along those lines could work). You'd need another statement for `contacts`, but would save looping/chaining `->save()` function.

Comment: Just write a method to perform the updates...  `$user->discounts->amount` won't work with a hasMany, discounts is a collection not an instance.

Comment: How about using the `sync()` method? [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: @MartijnICU I will look into it, thanks!

Comment: @MartijnICU The `->sync()`, along with `->attach()` and `->detach()` is only available for the `belongsToMany()` relationship, not the `hasMany()`/`belongsTo()` one.